# risky file local “outline-level”

Tags: file-local-variables, outline-mode, security

I'm reading [`(info "(emacs) 25.9.1 Format of Outlines")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Outline-Format.html#:%7E:text=with%20a%20file%20local%20variable):

> can explicitly specify a rule for calculating the level of a heading line by setting the variable `outline-level`. ...... The **recommended** ways to set this variable are in a major mode command or **with a *file local variable***.

But <kbd>C-h v outline-level</kbd>:

> This variable may be **risky** if **used as a *file-local variable***.

Why it may be risky?  Isn't it a recommended way to use file-locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its value is a function:

> Its value is ‘outline-level’
>
> Function of no args to compute a header’s nesting level in an outline.
> It can assume point is at the beginning of a header line and that the match
> data reflects the ‘outline-regexp’.

The function can do anything it wants, so such settings are inherently unsafe. Of course, if you are setting it to a value that you control, you can verify that the function  is benign and mark it as safe. But only *you* can do that for *your* setup: there is no way for somebody else to make sure of that.

As the OP points out in a comment below, the variable is always risky, not only when it is specified as a file local variable. And as @Drew points out, the point of the warning when it is specified as a file-local variable is to make sure that the user is alerted to the potential risk. If there were no warning, then the change would go into effect silently.

Comment: If this is the case, then the variable itself is unsafe, not only when it is file local.

Comment: Yes, not only when it is file-local. But when it is file-local, if there were no prompting then it would take effect without a user being aware of that.

Comment: Please allow me to add Drew's comment to your answer, then I accept it.

Comment: I edited it a bit. Please check and modify if you disagree.

Comment: Ah, I got it. This variable is declaimed as risky so that Emacs will *ask me to confirm* whether to apply it. I didn't know this before.